# display ajax response in div in ror

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am trying to display data from db using the value of a dropdown after a button is pressed through ajax.
This is my ajax code:

```
$(function () {
  $("button").click(function(){
       var value2 = $('select#dropdown option:selected').val();

       $.ajax({
           type: "GET", 
           dataType: "json",
           url:"/mycontroller/action2",
           data: {data1: value2 }, 
           success:function(result1){
                 console.log(result1);
                 result1.forEach(function(){
                 $res_html = $("<div class= 'result1'>" + result1 + "</div>");
                 $('#test1').append($res_html);

                $("#test1").text(result1);

                  })
            }
      })
  });
});
```

I have a div:

```
<div id= "test1"></div>
```

my problem is i am unable to display data in div tag of view in ror.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you missed id # prefix in the line $("test1").text(result1);

Comment: I have tried this.But the problem is not solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper syntax should be:

```
$("#test1").html(result1);
```

Answer (score 1):

add # in this line

```
$("test1").text(result1);
```

and use .html to append the html

```
 $(function()
    {
      $("button").click(function(){
            var value2 = $('select#dropdown option:selected').val();

       $.ajax({
            type: "GET", 
           dataType: "json",
           url: "/mycontroller/action2",
           data: { data1: value2 }, 
           success: function(result1){
                console.log(result1);
                var res_html = "";
                result1.forEach(function(){
                 res_html =+"<div class= 'result1'>" + result1 + "</div>";
                })
                 $("#test1").html(res_html);
            }
        })
  });
});
```

Comment: Hi I have tried this.The result is displayed in div but the result disappears in a blink.How can i solve this