# Showing data from Ajax response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to display my ajax response in a div, but I have no idea how to do that.

My code is the following:

```
<div class="divright">
   Div Content
</div>


< script >
  $(document).on("click", '.tribe-mini-calendar-day-link', function() {
    var date = $(this).data('day');
    $.ajax({

      type: "POST",
      url: TribeMiniCalendar.ajaxurl,
      data: {
        action: 'event_details',
        date: date
      },
      success: function(response) {
        console.log(response)
      },
      error: function(request, error) {
        alert("FOUT:" + error);
      }
    })
  })
</script>
```

If you click on `.tribe-mini-calendar-day-link`, the console says the following:

```
`{status: true, html: "<p><strong>Pratice: </strong> 2017-09-23 till 2017-09-24</p>"}`
```

Now my question is, how do I display that code in the `divright`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41362312/4673847

Comment: Welcome to SO. If you have no idea how to do something you should probably not post to SO. You should first get at least some basic idea and show some effort in solving the problem which you can consult here.

Answer (score 3):

Your success function should be :

```
success: function (response) {
   if(response !== undefined && response.html !== undefined) {
      $(".divright").html(response.html);
   }
},
```

Comment: plus 1 for checking is the string is not empty

Comment: Thank you! Youre comment was super usefull!

Answer (score 2):

In `success` section of AJAX request, assuming you are parsing `response` right way.

```
var data = response.html;
if(data !== undefined)
    $(".divright").html(data);
else
    $(".divright").html("Error!");
```

Comment: Thank you! Youre comment was super usefull!

Answer (score 1):

Inside your success function you need to append html to the div. This can be done very easily using jquery as

```
if(response !== undefined && response.html !== undefined){
    $( ".divright" ).html(response.html);
}
else{
    $( ".divright" ).html("<div>Some Error Encountered</div>");
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Youre comment was super usefull!

Answer (score 0):

You should use Jquery .html response to update data in your div tag .
 such as `$("#your_DIV_ID").html( data);`

Here is your your complete code.
`

```
<div id="my_Div_ID" class="divright"> Div Content </div>
    <script>
        $(document).on("click", '.tribe-mini-calendar-day-link', function() {
            var date = $(this).data('day');
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: TribeMiniCalendar.ajaxurl,
                data: {
                    action: 'event_details',
                    date: date
                },
                success: function(response) {
                    $("#my_Div_ID").html(response);
                    console.log(response)
                },
                error: function(request, error) {
                    alert("FOUT:" + error);
                }
            })
        })
    </script>
```

`

Comment: Thank you! Youre comment was super usefull!